# Linux: Take automatic screenshots at random times

Tags: linux, automation, cron, screenshot

I want automatic screenshots to be taken at random times throughout the day, preferably say 30 screenshots scheduled for independent random times.

This is so I can get a sort of representative sample of how I spend my time, and also to show other people, as a way of boosting my motivation to actually do useful stuff. I want the times to be random so that I don't look at the time and only start doing useful stuff right before the screenshot is to be taken; it'll be like a boss checking in on me unexpectedly. I also want some sort of notification right after a screenshot's been taken.

I'm on a standrad Ubuntu laptop. My problem: I am not sufficiently versed in cron-fu to figure out how to make it schedule tasks at random times. I also don't know how to do notifications from the command line.

This all seems like a pretty hard problem to me. Can any of you help?

Comment: IMO this question would be better at http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: Additionally, [what have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I used to do screen dumps with `xwd -silent -root > foo.xwd`

Answer (score 4):

There is `import`. Read up [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/import.php). Example:

```
import -window root -delay 200 screenshot.png
```

you can write a script to randomize.

Comment: That's very strange - I just tried that command, and it showed the windows on my screen in the reverse order of what they actually were - the ones that are hidden behind others showed up on-top.  I actually discovered that there was a pop-under I hadn't noticed by looking at the resulting .png file!

Comment: That's weird. I have only used it on several occasions. And mostly to take screenshots of my shell.

Comment: `import -screen screenshot.png` was slightly better, but still showed things in the wrong order.

Comment: `xwd -silent -root > foo.xwd` got the windows in the right order, but while gimp could display the .xwd file fine, doing `xwdtopnm|pnmtopng > foo.png` resulted in a corrupt file.

Answer (score 0):

not sure about `cron` launching a particular task at random times, but you can surely code this into a script that will launch at random times an application to take screenshots and do some sort of notification via the CLI or GUI.

Comment: The way to have cron do things at random times is to have them do it quite frequently, but have a random number generator decide if it should actually do the screen shot or not.  For example, if you set it up so that the cron runs every 10 minutes, but make it a 1 in a hundred chance that it actually produces the screen shot, you'll get a few every day.

Comment: but you would have to put the random generator function in a script file?

Comment: When I did this many years ago, I used the bash built-in RANDOM and the modulo operator.  (I did it to make a computer in a common area emit a "moo" sound every once in a while.  Not my fault - they had to give it the hostname "bovine" so what was I supposed to do?)